# Reversed double linked list by python

Tags: python, linked-list

why can't print reversed this double linked list by python?

always print 6 or None

please can anyone help me fast to pass this task

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None, prev=None):
            self.data = data
            self.next = next
            self.previous = prev
```

sample methods==>

```
    def set_data(self, newData):
        self.data = newData

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def set_next(self, newNext):
        self.next = newNext

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def hasNext(self):
        return self.next is not None

    def set_previous(self, newprev):
        self.previous = newprev

    def get_previous(self):
        return self.previous

    def hasPrevious(self):
        return self.previous is not None
```

class double===>

```
class DoubleLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def addAtStart(self, item):
        newNode = Node(item)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = newNode
        else:
            newNode.set_next(self.head)
            newNode.set_previous(None)
            self.head.set_previous(newNode)
            self.head = newNode

   
    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current is not None:
            count += 1
            current = current.get_next()
        return count
```

here is the wrong method ==>

try to fix it without more changes

```
def printReverse(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
        temp = current.next
        current.next = current.previous
        current.previous = temp
        current = current.previous
    temp = self.head
    self.head = self.tail
    self.tail = temp
    print("Nodes of doubly linked list reversed: ")
    while current is not None:
        print(current.data),
        current = current.get_next()
```

call methods==>

```
new = DoubleLinkedList()
new.addAtStart(1)
new.addAtStart(2)
new.addAtStart(3)
new.printReverse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printReverse` seems to do something else than what its name suggests. I would think that this function would just iterate the list nodes in reversed order and print the values, but it actually *reverses* the list, and doesn't print the result because of a bug.

The error in your code is that the final loop has a condition that is guaranteed to be false. `current` is always `None` when it reaches that loop, so nothing gets printed there. This is easily fixed by initialising `current` just before the loop with:

```
 current = self.head
```

That fixes your issue, but it is not nice to have a function that *both* reverses the list, *and* prints it. It is better practice to separate these two tasks. The method that reverses the list could be named `reverse`. Then add another method that allows iteration of the values in the list. This is done by defining `__iter__`. The caller can then easily print the list with that iterator.

Here is how that looks:

```
    def reverse(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            current.previous, current.next = current.next, current.previous
            current = current.previous
        self.head, self.tail = self.tail, self.head

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.data
            node = node.next

    def __repr__(self):
        return "->".join(map(repr, self))
```

The main program can then be:

```
lst = DoubleLinkedList()
lst.addAtStart(1)
lst.addAtStart(2)
lst.addAtStart(3)
print(lst)
lst.reverse()
print(lst)
```